# Winetricks does not appear in Open with menu

Tags: winetricks

I am in need of windows applications but I'm unable to run/execute the programs with wine tricks. As wine tricks does not appear in the open with menu. but it is present in Main menu.
I a a new user of Ubuntu. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Open with wine (not winetricks) is what you need to do.

[Winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks) is a helper script to install runtime libraries (like mfc42) needed by some executables (windows software). But after using winetricks, you will still use wine to open the executable.